# Can redis-py reliably use AWS ElastiCache Redis cluster?

Tags: redis, celery, amazon-elasticache, redis-py

I am trying to move away from a single AWS ElastiCache (Redis) server as Celery broker to a Redis cluster. Trouble is - nowhere in the Celery or redis-py documentation can I find the way to connect to the AWS RedisCluster.

redis-py that is used by Celery to communicate with the Redis server can be configured to use Redis Sentinel, but AWS does not support it (at least I did not find sentinel support in the AWS ElastiCache documentation).

So is there a way to communicate somehow with the ElastiCache Redis cluster using redis-py, or, is there a way to instruct Celery to use redis-py-cluster (a separate project)?

Answer (score 1):

Elasticache should give you a [configuration endpoint address](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticache/describe-cache-clusters.html) that you can use for connecting to celery.  Just use that endpoint in either the setting for the `broker_url` or `results_backend`.